# specific maximum between a list and a number in python

Tags: python, list

I want to do the maximum between the elements of a list L and a number "num" without doing a `for` loop. if an element of the list is greater than or equal to the number we keep it otherwise we put 0.

```
L=[12,34,65,98,67,56,76,67,98,52,67,100]
num=50
t=[]
for j in range(len(L)):
   if(L[i]> num):
      t.append(L[i])
```

I want to have the same result without making a loop. How can I do it?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you can use boolean indexing.  Return the items in the array where a condition is True.  Assuming L and num from the question.

```
import numpy as np
npl = np.array(L)

npl[ npl > num ]
# array([ 65,  98,  67,  56,  76,  67,  98,  52,  67, 100])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (though this is an implicit loop too):

```
t = [x for x in L if x > num]
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved upon Stef`s answer as you wanted a 0 if the number is smaller

```py
t = [x  if x >= num else 0 for x in L]
```